# "module" object has no attribute error when trying to get Checkbutton status

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get the status of the redundancyCheckbutton, in order to see if the `test.py` script should be run. As it works now, once a button is clicked, `run.py` fires off and runs the testSomething function fine. Whenever I try to get the status using `.get()` or something similar, it throws the module object has no attribute error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Also, would it be better to put the if statement in the `run.py` file or the `test.py` file? Thanks in advance.

---

## relevant lines of Tool.py

class ToolGui(Frame):
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.redundancyChecked = IntVar()

```
    self.redundancyCheckbutton = Checkbutton(rightframe, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,  text="Run Script?", variable=self.redundancyChecked)

    self.redundancyCheckbutton.pack(side=TOP, pady=(5,0))
```

---

## relevant lines of run.py

class Threading(threading.Thread):
    def runC(self, varis) :

```
    ####if checkbutton is checked, run this...could go here

    test.trySomething(workDir)
```

---

## relevant lines of test.py

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess


def trySomething(dir):
    import Tool
  ###or If statement could go here, not sure which would be better
    Tool.redundancyCheckbutton.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: Please show the actual error -- it tells you both which module, and what attribute. As a rule of thumb, you should take the error message literally and assume it is telling the truth.

Answer (score 0):

`redundancyCheckbutton` belongs to an instance of some instance of a class. I don't know what class, because you didn't show enough code.

The line that is likely causing the problem (I'm assuming, since you didn't show the actual error message) is this:

```
import Tool
Tool.redundancyCheckbutton.config(...)
```

In this context, `Tool` is a module. This module does not have a `redundancyCheckbutton` attribute, just like the error message is telling you. Again, the attribute belongs to an *object*, not a *module*.

Most likely, somewhere in `Tool` you define a class. Since you didn't say, for the purpose of this answer I'll say it was named `GUI`. Therefore, you have a module `Tool`, with a class `GUI`. This class defines an attribute `self.redundancyCheckbutton`.

The only way to create that checkbutton is to create an instance of that class. So, somewhere in your code you must be doing something like this:

```
gui = GUI(...) # or maybe Tool.GUI(...)
```

Therefore, to access `redundancyCheckbutton` you must use `gui.redundancyCheckbutton`, because it is an attribute of an object, which is defined by a class, which is in the Tools module.

Comment: this is correct. Tool.py contains a class and function:

ToolGui(Frame):

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.redundancyChecked = IntVar() ... and so on with the checkbutton

so how would I get the redundancyChecked value? make an instance of it?

Comment: @burghermeister: you don't need to make _another_ instance of it. For the checkbutton to exist you must have already created an instance. You just need to keep a reference to that instance.